# Audio plays in GraphEdit but not WMP

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, directshow, ape

I have trouble with only one file format. I can play my files just fine in GraphEdit and GraphStudio, but WMP absolutely refuses them. In typical Microsoft fashion, it gives no helpful error. In fact it gives no error at all. It just pretends that I like to play zero-length audio tracks. Is there anything I can do to get to the bottom of this?

Specifically, I'm fighting APE. I've tried RadLight, DSP-Worx, and Monkey's Audio filters.

Comment: Does that require a separate codec for WMP? If so have you re-installed it? Also, you didn’t mention this but are you launching the file then it’s automatically opening in WMP because it’s associated with it?

Comment: Yes it requires codecs. I've tried the ones I listed. My goal is to play everything through WMP. This is the only loose end. It doesn't matter if I associate or unassociate and drag/drop. WMP just doesn't want to comply, despite complete success with low-level DirectShow tools.

Comment: By "Monkey's Audio filters" you mean Monkey's Audio 4.11 (latest as of this date), right?

Comment: Monkey's Audio is working fine in WMP on my Windows 7 system. If you're using the 64-bit version of WMP then I suggest that you try the 32-bit version. The 64-bit one can't load 32-bit codecs.

Answer (score 0):

WMP plays through Media Foundation, and if unable to do so then it tries DirectShow. As you see that DirectShow playback is in good standing, the likely problem here is that WMP's attempt to play through Media Foundation succeeds "enough" for the applciation to conisder playback setup successful, however it cannot read actual data from there. There is little you can do as you cannot alter WMPs behavior in choice of API to use. What you can do is to use another playback application.